# Properly 301 redirect an URL with parameters to a different site

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Right now I have an outdated URL that is getting 404'd:

```
http://mysite.com/category/?tag=blue-example
```

It needs to be redirected to:

```
http://subdomain.mysite.com/blue/
```

This doesn't work:

```
Redirect 301 /category/?tag=blue-example http://subdomain.mysite.com/blue/
```

How do I properly rewrite this URL?

Comment: What didn't work? Where exactly did you put that line? Should the URL to redirect to be dependent on the QUERY_STRING? Your question is vague.

Comment: Sorry about being vague. When I use that re-direct rule the original URL does not redirect to the new URL. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) does only chech the URI path and not the query (the part after the `?`). But you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =tag=blue-example
RewriteRule ^category/$ http://subdomain.example.com/blue/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo! This appears to be what I am looking for but for some reason it is not working on my local install. I am using a bunch of other mod_rewrite rules that are working.